# What is the more efficient output type for an UDF to return an array

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark SQL and an UDF is used to compute a column of type `ArrayType`

What is the fastest output type in term of performance ?

Spark accept any implemention of trait `Seq` but I think it's represented internally by a `WrappedArray` (into tungsten).

So I'm wondering if it's better to return an `Array` instead of a `Vector` for example, to avoid some encoding.

Comment: spark sql should be better as it is optimized for JVM whereas udf requires expensive serialization and deserialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it's represented internally by a WrappedArray (into tungsten).

It is not. `WrappedArray` (literally an `Array` augmented to fit into `scala.collection` API) is the external representation. Internal representation (excluding primitive types) doesn't depend on standard Scala API.

> So I'm wondering if it's better to return an Array instead of a Vector for example, to avoid some encoding.

It won't make a difference. Output from the `udf` is fully encoded element-by-element. It is not possible to avoid full copy of the returned value.

If the processing cannot be done with (quite limited) SQL API, you're stuck with what you have, until higher order functions API is open sourced by Databricks.